# React Native iOS: RCT_EXPORT_METHOD and out of sync

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native

I am facing some out of sync type of issue on React Native iOS.

on file *RTCComponentManager.m*, I define a list of function

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(function1:(type)parameterA parameterB :(type) parameterB) {}
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(function2:(type)parameterA parameterB :(type) parameterB) {}
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(function3:(type)parameterA parameterB :(type) parameterB) {}
```

and in file *component.ios.js*:

```
function1 = (parameterA, parameterB) => {
  this.sendCommand(UIManager.getViewManagerConfig('RCTComponent').Commands.function1, [parameterA, parameterB]);
};

function2 = (parameterA, parameterB) => {
   this.sendCommand(UIManager.getViewManagerConfig('RCTComponent').Commands.function2, [parameterA, parameterB]);
};

function3 = (parameterA, parameterB) => {
   this.sendCommand(UIManager.getViewManagerConfig('RCTComponent').Commands.function3, [parameterA, parameterB]);
};
```

For some reason it appears that calling javascript *function1* would end up in calling native *function2*,  and error message like this appears:

> Component.function2 was called with 6 arguments but expects 2
> arguments. If you haven't changed this method yourself, this usually
> means that your versions of the native code and JavaScript code are
> out of sync.

What could be the root cause ?
I tried various commands like *pod deintegrate*, *pod install*, *xcode Product clean build folder*, *xcode Product build*, *npx react-native run-ios* without much success.

Any hint is most welcome !